# a private copy constructor: disallow

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I'm programming in an open source library which has very little comments in the code, and absolutely no code related documentation, or such comments which show absolutely nothing or are completely confusing. An example class of the library is sometimes defined as follows (this is an abstracted short example):

```
class A
{
    private:

    // Disallow default bitwise copy construct. 
    A (const A& Acopy) { data = Acopy.data; };

    int data;

    public:

    A() {};

    A (int arg) : data(arg) {};

    A(const A& Acopy) { data = Acopy.data; };

};
```

The comment "Dissalow default bitwise copy construct" in front of a **private** copy constructor would point to the fact that when I define a type I need to define my own copy constructor to avoid one being "generated" for me ambiguously by the compiler. This is what I have learned so far on this topic. But in this case, the constructor is **private**, and the compilation breaks in this form.

Q: Is there a reason for such thing? A copy constructor that is private? And what could this comment mean?

Tomislav

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means pretty much what you said. Normally, the compiler would generate a copy constructor. To prevent this, you can define your own, and make it private. Then any attempt at copy-constructing the class will fail at compile-time, rather than silently doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Usually, the copy constructor is just declared private and not implemented and the assignment operator receive the same handling. Rare are the cases were you don't want a public copy constructor but a private one is meaningful.

Comment: If I define any copy constructor **private** or **public**, the compiler will not generate one. If the compiler is given a reference and not a value as an argument, it will take the reference and not the value. If it is private, it cannot be called from outside of the class, and two of them may not exist. Does this all mean that the template for the Class is written like this to force the programmer to define his own public copy(or private) constructor?

Comment: No, when written like this, it is to *prevent* the class from being copied *at all*. Once a copy constructor exists, you can't create a second one. And if it is private, then it effectively means that the class cannot be copied.

Comment: But the template file for the class has both **public** and **private** constructor declared and defined and it does not compile. This template is generated by an automatic script and it is used to provide a starting point for programming with this library. This template, of course (because it has both private and public two copy constructors) does not compile at all. So, I can either choose to have a private copy constructor if I don't want my class to be copied at all (from outside), or a public one?

Comment: @tomislav-maric: Given that you don't know which one to choose, First You should keep it `private` and check if you can compile the library. If not then you should keep the `public` one.

Comment: I do know which one to choose,this will depend on the nature of my data type. Thanks, now everything is clear. Two of them may not exist. They are both there to prevent the programmer in not providing a copy constructor. A choice is required from the programmer to either keep the private or public one. :) Cool. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @tomislav: yes, depending on which one you keep, you make the class copyable or noncopyable

Comment: Great, an anonymous downvote. Wish I knew why, but I'm sure there's a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, A copy constructor is made private to disallow Passing of objects by value.

Answer (score 3):

The compilation breaks, I think, because the copy constructor is defined twice, once as private and once as public.

A reason for a private copy constructor might be to prevent an instance of A being passed or returned by value. Why one would want to do this is another matter, which I can't answer.

Answer (score 3):

The point is, as you said, to avoid generating default copy constructors, but not only that - it's `private` to avoid actually using it. The point of making it private is not to allow using it.

Answer (score 1):

Compilation breaks because you have two copy constructors, one public and one private. Private copy constrcutors are perfectly alright. They disallows many dangerous things that the user can do.